# How to automate a Wake On Lan command in GRUB2 boot

Tags: boot, grub2, wakeonlan

I have 3 computers in my home installation, one (call it **FREEBNT**) is my server, with Ubuntu server 22.04.1 LTS, acting mainly as a NAS server. Other (call it **XAUDIOSERVER**) is a Ubuntu Desktop with audio functionality. And the third one (call it **TACENS10**) is my main PC, where I work, with Windows 10 installed.

All of them are available to Wake up via WOL, and I usually wake them on all because I use all of them at the same time. I can wake them up via a WOL app in my Android phone. But now, what I want to achieve, is to automate a command at **TACENS10** boot, so that, when I power on **TACENS10**, it automatically wakes up the other two computers. I imagine that it could be easier to do with GRUB2 than the Windows 10 bootloader. So I'm available to repartition my hard disk to include a (GRUB2) partition if necessary.

I have searched in google and this forum and I didn't see anything seeming like my problem.

So, is it possible to run a Wake-On-Lan command from GRUB2? and, how do I install and configure GRUB2 to do this task? I (obviously) have the MAC addresses of both computers.
Also note, that I don't have Ubuntu installed on my **TACENS10**, nor I'm planning to do, so I would need to run a Live Ubuntu session and create a boot partition, to include only Windows 10, or maybe if I can, **Windows 10 - WakeOnLAN** and also **Windows 10 - no WakeOnLAN**, in case I don't want to wake up the others.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to start `TACENS10` the this ubuntu serever should start 2 other server via WOL. 
Ubuntu has a `wakeonlan` packeage that dos WOL. Grub (or grub2) is not the place to do this, but you may write simple service (or cron) that does the job at boot.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but the only limitation to your idea is that in **TACENS10** I don't have Ubuntu installed, but Windows 10. So I need to use GRUB2. Are you sure I can't do it from GRUB2?

Comment: @BorHacker Grub2 doesn't provide such a feature, thus it's not possible to do.